# iptables/nat/prerouting ignores UDP packets?

Tags: iptables, nat, linux-networking, dnat

The same effect on many servers with various kernel versions.

There are multiple Iptables DNAT rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.30.40:5678
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 23456 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.11.12.13:5789
....
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 34567 -j LOG --log-prefix 'natudp: '
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 34567 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.55.66.77:34567
```

**Problem:  UDP rules are not working for incoming requests from eth0.**
Packet and bytes counters for them have zero values.
Simplification (removing dport) has no effect.
As result, requests are passed to filter/INPUT chain instead of FORWARD.

No such problem for packets from virtual interfaces (tap, veth) - they are  trapped by prerouting rules.
No such problem for TCP.
No such problem for UDP **answers**.
But incoming UDP requests from eth0 are ignored by prerouting rules at all:

```
# iptables -t nat -nvL PREROUTING
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 174 bytes)
 pkts bytes target   prot opt in     out   source        destination         

(testing rules)
    2   126 LOG      udp  --  *      *     0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0      LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "prerouting-udp: "
    0     0          udp  --  *      *     1.2.3.4       0.0.0.0/0               
    0     0          udp  --  *      *     1.2.3.4       0.0.0.0/0      udp dpt:25826
    0     0          udp  --  eth0   *     0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0      udp dpt:25826
    0     0          udp  --  eth0   *     1.2.3.4       0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0          udp  --  eth0   *     1.2.3.4       0.0.0.0/0      udp dpt:25826

(production rules)
    7   412 DNAT     tcp  --  eth0   *     0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0      tcp dpt:12345 to:10.20.30.40:8080
   63  3804 DNAT     tcp  --  eth0   *     0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0      tcp dpt:56789 to:10.30.40.50:8000
    0     0 DNAT     udp  --  eth0   *     1.2.3.4       0.0.0.0/0      udp dpt:25826 to:10.40.50.60:25826
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give us the result of `iptables -t nat -L PREROUTING -n` ?

Comment: Could you add the 2 lines of LOG in UDP ?

Comment: Why the packets should come FROM 1.2.3.4. They should be on the destination, if 1.2.3.4 is your IP.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here. As the last thing to check, check the conntrack table. In my case, resetting the tracked connections make the rules work instantly.

```
apt install conntrack -y
# see current UDP connection
conntrack -L -p udp --dport 34567
# in OP's case purge tracking entries per rule U:dport=34567
conntrack -D -p udp --dport 34567
# if not care
# conntrack -D -p udp
```

Or if uptime is not vital for the device, simply reboot which is another way of `conntrack -D`.